# Using Input properly with datalines

Tags: sas

I need to figure out the correct input statement to read in the data from datalines.

Tried pointers and positional values

```
data oscar;
    input @1 oscardate $ @9 oscaryear @14 budget dollar11. gross dollar13. 
        +1 title $16. +1 asofdate mmddyy10. +1 rating 3.1;
    format asofdate mmddyy10. budget dollar12. gross dollar13.;
    datalines;
27Feb11 2011 $15,000,000 $373,700,000 The Kings Speech 02/26/2012 8.2
07Mar10 2010 $11,000,000 $12,647,089 The Hurt Locker 02/26/2012 7.2
22Feb09 2009 $15,000,000 $141,319,195 Slumdog Millionaire 02/26/2012 8.2
24Feb08 2008 $25,000,000 $74,273,505 No Country for Old Men 02/26/2012 8.2
25Feb07 2007 $90,000,000 $289,800,000 The Departed 02/26/2012 8.5
05Mar06 2006 $6,500,000 $98,410,061 Crash 02/26/2012 8.0
;
run;
```

I want to be able to print out the values as written in the data lines

Comment: Any reason you are reading the first date as a string instead of a date?  Do you have any way to fix the data lines so that they have proper delimiters?  Currently the lines are using spaces as delimiters, but the value of TITLE contains spaces on some lines.  If you could fix that then the line could be read.

Answer (score 2):

Use an `attrib` statement to declare and specify the attributes of the variables being input.  The code will be a cleaner read (for humans) than having a smattering of other attribute affecting statements and perhaps implicit determination from the `input` statement.

When the data has a character value with multiple internal single spaces you should either offset the value from others using two spaces (and use `&` input modifier), or double quote the data value (and use `infile cards dsd dlm=" "`).

For example, the title is bounded by two spaces:

```
data oscar;
  attrib
    oscardate format=date9. informat=date9.
    oscaryear format=4.
    budget    format=dollar13.0 informat=dollar13.0
    gross     format=dollar13.0 informat=dollar13.0
    title     length=$200
    asofdate  format=mmddyy10. informat=mmddyy10.
    rating    format=4.1
  ;

  input oscardate oscaryear budget gross & title & asofdate rating;
datalines;
27Feb11 2011 $15,000,000 $373,700,000  The Kings Speech  02/26/2012 8.2
07Mar10 2010 $11,000,000 $12,647,089  The Hurt Locker  02/26/2012 7.2
22Feb09 2009 $15,000,000 $141,319,195  Slumdog Millionaire  02/26/2012 8.2
24Feb08 2008 $25,000,000 $74,273,505  No Country for Old Men  02/26/2012 8.2
25Feb07 2007 $90,000,000 $289,800,000  The Departed  02/26/2012 8.5
05Mar06 2006 $6,500,000 $98,410,061  Crash  02/26/2012 8.0
run;
```

For the case of particularly pernicious data lines you might need to do an `input;` to fill the automatic `_infile_` variable with the entire line and then use Perl regular expression pattern matching to extract desired parts.

Other data lines constructions would be ensuring **all** data fields are aligned column-wise, in which case the `@` modifier can be used to read a value starting at a particular column.

`input` has so many features there is no best way or single correct statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your current lines are not formatted in a way that makes it possible to parse them. This is because they are using space for the delimiter between fields, but the TITLE field also includes spaces. There are a number of ways you could fix the datalines to make it possible to parse them.

You could convert the lines to use a different delimiter that does not appear in any field.  Pipe character is useful. Tab ('09'x) is also common.

```
27Feb11|2011|$15,000,000|$373,700,000|The Kings Speech|02/26/2012|8.2
```

You could add quotes around any value that contain the delimiter (or quotes).

```
27Feb11 2011 $15,000,000 $373,700,000 "The Kings Speech" 02/26/2012 8.2
```

You could use fixed length fields.

```
27Feb11 2011    $15,000,000 $373,700,000  The Kings Speech        02/26/2012 8.2
07Mar10 2010    $11,000,000  $12,647,089  The Hurt Locker         02/26/2012 7.2
22Feb09 2009    $15,000,000 $141,319,195  Slumdog Millionaire     02/26/2012 8.2
24Feb08 2008    $25,000,000  $74,273,505  No Country for Old Men  02/26/2012 8.2
```

If like in this case only one field might contain the delimiter place that one at the end of the line.

```
27Feb11 2011 $15,000,000 $373,700,000 02/26/2012 8.2 The Kings Speech
```

For SAS you could also just insure that your TITLE value does not contain multiple spaces next to each other and then make sure that there are at least two spaces after the Title. Then the `&` modifier on the `INPUT` statement will tell SAS to allow spaces in the value but stop reading that field when it sees two adjacent spaces.

```
27Feb11 2011 $15,000,000 $373,700,000 The Kings Speech  02/26/2012 8.2
07Mar10 2010 $11,000,000 $12,647,089 The Hurt Locker  02/26/2012 7.2
22Feb09 2009 $15,000,000 $141,319,195 Slumdog Millionaire  02/26/2012 8.2
24Feb08 2008 $25,000,000 $74,273,505 No Country for Old Men  02/26/2012 8.2
```

If you cannot fix the input lines and **only one field** has embedded spaces, then you could parse the line in your code.  So for this one I would just read that last three fields into the TITLE value and then pull out the date and rating and remove them.

```
data oscar;
  infile datalines truncover;
  length oscardate 8 oscaryear 8 budget 8  gross 8 title $50 asofdate 8 rating 8;
  informat oscardate date. budget gross dollar. asofdate mmddyy. ;
  format oscardate asofdate yymmdd10. budget gross dollar12. rating 4.1 ;
  input oscardate -- gross title $50. ;
  rating = input(scan(title,-1,' '),32.);
  asofdate = input(scan(title,-2,' '),mmddyy10.);
  title = substrn(title,1,length(title)-length(scan(title,-1,' '))-length(scan(title,-2,' '))-2);
datalines;
27Feb11 2011 $15,000,000 $373,700,000 The Kings Speech 02/26/2012 8.2
07Mar10 2010 $11,000,000 $12,647,089 The Hurt Locker 02/26/2012 7.2
22Feb09 2009 $15,000,000 $141,319,195 Slumdog Millionaire 02/26/2012 8.2
24Feb08 2008 $25,000,000 $74,273,505 No Country for Old Men 02/26/2012 8.2
25Feb07 2007 $90,000,000 $289,800,000 The Departed 02/26/2012 8.5
05Mar06 2006 $6,500,000 $98,410,061 Crash 02/26/2012 8.0
;
```

If you want to write a new version of the data as text that can be parsed use the DSD option on a FILE statement and a simple put statement.

```
339  data _null_;
340   set oscar;
341   file log dsd dlm=' ' ;
342   put oscardate -- rating ;
343  run;

2011-02-27 2011 $15,000,000 $373,700,000 "The Kings Speech" 2012-02-26 8.2
2010-03-07 2010 $11,000,000 $12,647,089 "The Hurt Locker" 2012-02-26 7.2
2009-02-22 2009 $15,000,000 $141,319,195 "Slumdog Millionaire" 2012-02-26 8.2
2008-02-24 2008 $25,000,000 $74,273,505 "No Country for Old Men" 2012-02-26 8.2
2007-02-25 2007 $90,000,000 $289,800,000 "The Departed" 2012-02-26 8.5
2006-03-05 2006 $6,500,000 $98,410,061 Crash 2012-02-26 8.0
```